# SurfaceView sample code

Tags: android, surfaceview, demo

I need a sample tutorial for the android `SurfaceView`, or sample code using it that can be shared. The API demos are difficult for me to understand. Does anyone have alternatives?

Comment: Download the LunarLander demo. There are tons of websites discussing it.

Comment: do u have any easy samples??? i'm new to android..

Comment: It doesn't get a whole lot easier when it comes to a full game application.  You have to devote the time and a game application is by far _not_ the easiest thing to learn.

Comment: try this http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html

Comment: read the documentations on android dev, there is a tutorial on what your looking for; if you can't understand that then u got to do your java basics

Comment: I agree that the samples aren't the best source of information on SurfaceView for all cases.  I am looking for the *simplest* implementation(s) of a functional SurfaceView, and am having trouble understanding what the minimum requirements are for a skeleton framework of drawing on a surface view.  I've been looking at the Lunar Lander sample, but can't work out what's specific to the game, and what's required for using a SurfaceView.

Answer (score 7):

[This commit](https://github.com/johnnylambada/WorldMap/commit/7b94ac1b9a1e1144e173b62e6f0805ee81e2e030) of my [WorldMap demo app](https://github.com/johnnylambada/WorldMap) shows you the changes necessary to convert from an [android.view.View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) to an [android.view.SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) with an [android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html).

It cheats a bit by using the `View`'s `onDraw()` from within the `SurfaceView`'s `DrawThread` and by calling the `View`'s `onSizeChanged()` from within the `SurfaceView`'s `surfaceChanged`. It just makes the diff smaller and easier to understand.

Comment: crazy as (i believe) your solution is, it was the easiest fix for me, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks (I guess :). Care to explain why it's crazy?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're needing a `GLSurfaceView` or not, but [glbuffer](https://github.com/richq/glbuffer/) is one of my favorite examples.

This is the java file where the action happens: [GlBufferActivity](https://github.com/richq/glbuffer/blob/master/src/glbuffer/app/GlBufferActivity.java)

The project also relies on native methods and the NDK, so it may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's a great starting point if you want to work with OpenGL via the normal C apis.

Comment: can you share the sample snippet??

Comment: I added the link to the java file

Comment: hey can i have three buttons over the surface view.. is it possible??

Comment: I believe so, if you use a FrameLayout.